# Select all picture,images,saved pictures from device

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, media-library

I am developing one application related to Pictures, Album. What I am trying to do is to select all pictures, saved picture, album, camera roll from **device** and store it in `List<Image>`. I found one class i.e. **MediaLibrary**, but I am not able to understand how can I select all these images and store it in list.

Is it possible to add all picture in list like follows.

```cs
 private void btnSearchImages_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();            

        foreach (var r in m.Pictures)
        {
            Stream imageStream = r.GetImage();
            List<Image> lstImageFromMediaLibrary = new List<Image>();
            var imageToShow = new Image()
            {
                Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(r.GetImage())
            };

            lstImageFromMediaLibrary.Add(imageToShow);
        }        
    }
```

When I debug it, I found there is no images, even when there is 8 default images in **album**. **m.Pictures** shows count zero. How can I select all these images from device and add it in a list?

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();

```
    foreach (var r in m.RootPictureAlbum.Pictures)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my all images in my list. I have just added `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO` from manifest is selected.(manifest is located on Properties > WMAppManifest.xml > Capabilities )

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem in your code is that your always declare a new list for each iteration. You should do:

```
private void btnSearchImages_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();            

    List<Image> lstImageFromMediaLibrary = new List<Image>();

    foreach (var r in m.Pictures)
    {
        Stream imageStream = r.GetImage();

        var imageToShow = new Image()
        {
            Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(r.GetImage())
        };

        lstImageFromMediaLibrary.Add(imageToShow);
    }        
}
```